# Attach points in dijit.Dialog, when using template as content

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo

I am instantiating a dijit.Dialog programmatically and want to set a form as the content. This is defined in a HTML template, which I load like:

```
"dojo/text!./templates/CustomTabControllerEditGroupDialog.html",
```

and set during construction:

```
var myDialog = new Dialog({ ... content: template, ... });
```

Now I want to have data-dojo-attach-points and -events in my template, but I don't get where they point to. How do I do this?
I know the issue of extending a dialog is an ongoing discussion, but I honestly think I should be possible to display a form programmatically without creating a new Dialog widget.
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the html template as the content, create a custom widget that uses the template and set an instance of the widget as the dialog content.  Attach points in the template will become variables on the widget.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_AttachMixin.html#dijit-attachmixin

Comment: That's fine and solves my problem. Nevertheless I will try to implement an extended Dialog that takes a html template, widgetifies it by itself and allows setting the attach scope to the instantiating widget. Thanks.